# How to remove a line containing specific string from file with sed command

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I have the following file :

```
#!example
#!toto
example
#example
;example
toto
example
```

I want to remove the lines containing the string `"example"` except the lines start with `"#!"`.

So the result file should be:

```
#!example
#!toto
toto
```

How to do it with only `sed` command?

Comment: +1 for example input and required output. As you grow in skill, please recall that Stackoverflow is about improving programming skills, not just improved requirement specfication ; -) *You should include code for what you have tried so far AND error messages and incorrect output) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this line:

```
 sed '/^#!/n;/example/d' file
```

test with your example text:

```
kent$  cat file
#!example
#!toto
example
#example
;example
toto
example

kent$  sed '/^#!/n;/example/d' file
#!example
#!toto
toto
```

if you like, **awk** could do it too:

```
kent$  awk '/^#!/ || !/example/' file                                                                                                                 
#!example
#!toto
toto
```

**EDIT**

sed:

- if line matches `starting with #!`, stop processing, go to next line (`n`)
- if above checking failed (doesn't match `#!`), check if containing `example`, if yes, `d` delete (do not print in output)

awk

- print all lines with:

  - starting with `#!` or (`||`) not containing example.

performance:

I cannot really tell. because the requirement is simple enough. You could build a huge file, and use `time` to compare by yourself.

Comment: (+1) good answer could you explain the `sed` and `awk` commands you used, and what is the best concerning time execution and ressources

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI explanation added

Comment: does awk edit file in place like sed does with the `-i` option?

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI no. but you could `awk '..' file > /tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo /path/to/file`

Comment: I think the sed solution might fail if there were 2 successive lines beginning `#! example`.

Comment: potong's feedback is easily verified, I tested with successive blocks of one, two, three, ... repeating `#!example` lines. Their answer below, which replaces `n` with `b` is correct. I still upvoted because this answer is helpful & provides a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep only lines starting with `#!`

```
$ sed '/#!/!d' foo.sh
#!example
#!toto
```

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI : Are you sure? Did you try it? It works for me. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#!/b;/example/d' file
```

This prints all lines containing `#!` and all other lines except those containing `example`.